# Exponential function and fractions

Tags: logarithms, exponential-function, transcendental-equations

I am not sure how to solve the following type of equation, would appreciate the help. Thanks.

$$e^{0.25x-2} = \frac{x+3}{3x+3} $$

After taking $\ln$ to both sides, I am not sure what to do with the RHS. I can only break them up into $\ln(x+3) - \ln(3x+3)$. Where would I go from there?

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK this does not have closed-form solutions (even using the Lambert W function).  Numerical methods or series are the way to go.

Comment: how would I go about doing that? What would you suggest I use specifically?